# Задать время, большее 24 часов, в QTimeEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Я хочу задать в виджете `QTimeEdit` время большее, чем `23:59:59.999`. Судя по документации это сделать невозможно. Поэтому я создала наследника этого класса и переопределила функцию:

```
QValidator::State validate(QString & text, int & pos) const
```

Теперь я могу с клавиатуры написать в виджете, например, `00:00:999`. Но когда переключаю на другой виджет, то время сбрасывается на `00:00:00`. С помощью стрелок и колесика мыши увеличить составляющие значения времени больше допустимых  также нельзя.

Какие методы еще нужно перезагружать?

Comment: Боюсь Вам придётся повозиться с этим классом и не факт, что из этого что-то выйдет. Он просто для этого не предназначен. Проще написать свой виджет, скорее всего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значение сбрасывается на 00:00:00, т.к. введенный вами текст виджет пытается преобразовать в `QDateTimeEdit`. Попробуйте унаследоваться от `QLineEdit` и задайте маску ввода:
`QLineEdit::setInputMask("DDD:DDD:DDD")`
Далее переопределите нужные вам events, которые будут изменять текущую секцию, которую можно определять исходя из `QLineEdit::cursorPosition()`